# how to send image from url using telethon

Tags: python, telethon

I want to know how to send image or media from a URL link,

```
file = BOT.upload_file('/user/home/photo.jpg')
BOT.send_file(chat , file)
```

I know that using this method we can send image from path, but I want to know if its possible to send it from a URL link. but I am trying to run the code on Heruku so uploading it from the patch will not be possible so if there is a way to send it using a URL link please tell me how to do that.

can anyone help me figure this out please.

Comment: Please read the description of tags before using them.

Answer (score 0):

1. you don't have to explicitly upload a file, telethon does it internally, so:

```py
BOT.send_file(chat , '/user/home/photo.jpg')
```

is enough (unless you're willing to resend something pre-uploaded multiple times)

2. likewise, you can pass a URL to send_file, Telegram servers will fetch it and send by itself (note there are limits for file size, 5MB for images, 20 MB for documents)

```py
BOT.send_file(chat , url)
```

Comment: its showing error when i try to do that. should i write it as 'URL'????

Comment: The url has to be string ofcource, 'https....'

Comment: it saying this error telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.MediaEmptyError: The provided media object is invalid or the current account may not be able to send it (such as games as users) (caused by SendMediaRequest)

Comment: what does it mean, please explain and how to solve it?

Comment: The content in your URL is invalid. it's up to server to decide, try with something else like `https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/se/se-logo.png`

Comment: yeah that is working. but do you know any websites that support this, because i want to send the pic that i have.

Comment: and is it possife to send gifs in mp4 formap in url links?

Comment: ok i figured out how to send the images but do you know how to send a mp4 file , like is it the same method , just replace the url????????

Comment: ⁪⁬⁪⁬⁮⁪⁬⁪⁬⁮⁪⁬yes